# Setting yearRange of datepicker from javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

```
$(".parent_div").delegate(".input_control", "focusin", function () {
    var year = $('#this_year_input').val();
    var year_text = "'" + year + ":" + year + "'";
    $(this).attr("readonly", "true");
    $(this).datepicker({
        "dateFormat": 'mm/dd/yy',
            "changeMonth": true,
            "changeYear": true,
            "yearRange": year_text
    });
});
```

I am trying to restrict user by selecting dates for the year he is selecting. Reason is I have multiple datepicker controls and I need the same year that user selected once.
So I provided dropdown of year and getting value from it in variable 'year'.
Now this is what happens.
Problem is that if 'this_year_input' has 2010, var year_text get '2010:2010' but the it doesn't work in calender control. If I replace year_text with '2010:2010' in argument, it works

Answer (score 2):

You can give like

```
$(this).datepicker({
    "dateFormat": 'mm/dd/yy',
        "changeMonth": true,
        "changeYear": true,
        "yearRange": year + ":" + year
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [yearRange](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange)

```
var year_text = year + ":" + year ;
```

or

```
"yearRange":  year + ":" + year
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like this

```
$(function() {
    var minYear=1990;
    var maxYear=2000;
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        yearRange: minYear+':'+ maxYear,
        changeYear: true

    });
});
```

[CHECK THIS LIVE JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kGjdL/457/)